# Error facebook bot [HELP]

Tags: facebook, git, bots

I'm trying to create a facebook bot using this tutorial https://github.com/jw84/messenger-bot-tutorial/tree/master/ .
I'm getting this error when I try to open the server writing *node index.js* in the Terminal.

```
events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::5000
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:896:20)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1250:14)
at listen (net.js:1286:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1382:5)
at EventEmitter.listen (/Users/lauralisboa/Desktop/botchi/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:617:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/lauralisboa/Desktop/botchi/index.js:65:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
```

The code which I have on the index.js file is this one (copy paste from the tutorial):

'use strict'

```
    const express = require('express')
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    const request = require('request')
    const app = express()

    app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000))

    // Process application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

    // Process application/json
    app.use(bodyParser.json())

    // Index route
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
            res.send('Hello world, I am a chat bot')
    })

    // for Facebook verification
    app.get('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
            if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === 'my_voice_is_my_password_verify_me') {
                res.send(req.query['hub.challenge'])
            }
            res.send('Error, wrong token')
    })

    app.post('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
            let messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging
            for (let i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
                let event = req.body.entry[0].messaging[i]
                let sender = event.sender.id
                if (event.message && event.message.text) {
                    let text = event.message.text
                    sendTextMessage(sender, "Text received, echo: " + text.substring(0, 200))
                }
            }
            res.sendStatus(200)
    })

    const token="EAAXaNuLUMG8BAHDd3XJBhGNFQT2D6D5z8QfkOZAgKFWYVyiXh29r9jeZATDYFHseoFdHxBmizWUIyDK8YyVJCsTpNlrtJuS5Ia4qSeAZASkZCKqlnvPlw3EDw5IiZB1mEnLe6N9iZAqbDu050EbVSsSVbYFRl9BxiyWmoYLuEDOAZDZD"

    function sendTextMessage(sender, text) {
            let messageData = { text:text }
            request({
                url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
                qs: {access_token:token},
                method: 'POST',
                json: {
                    recipient: {id:sender},
                    message: messageData,
                }
            }, function(error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('Error sending messages: ', error)
                } else if (response.body.error) {
                    console.log('Error: ', response.body.error)
                }
            })
    }
```

// Spin up the server

```
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {

console.log('running on port', app.get('port'))
```

})

Thank for your attention, Laura

Comment: Looks like the port is already in use. Do you have another instance of the script running? What Operating System are you developing this on?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on your local box or on a Heroku box?  If you are on a local box then another process is using port 5000. If you are on a Linux flavor then sudo netstat -anlp can help find which process is using the port.   Could it be another instance of the same job?

In many ways running the application fully on Heroku is simpler.  See my article [Facebook Bots for Fun and Profit](https://medium.com/@matthewericfisher/facebook-bots-for-fun-and-profit-490245c3797c)  It points to a similar setup of a FB Bot but with the app running completely on Heroku. The example appears more full featured than the one you are working with.

The example bot is [DMS Software Bot](https://m.me/dynamicmemorysolutions)

The source code is [Github fb-robot](https://github.com/matthewericfisher/fb-robot)

Comment: Good luck with your Bot, I've had a lot of fun with mine.   If my answer was helpful please accept it or up vote it.